# transpiling JSX without Babel

Tags: reactjs

Is there a stand-alone transpiler for converting JSX to JavaScript (i.e. just `<foo … />` → `createElement("foo", …)`, nothing else)?

I know I could just use Babel with the transform-react-jsx plugin, but would not want to prescribe an ES6 transpiler.

Comment: [help/on-topic]: _Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be using Babel, since the other standalone packages are not being updated/maintained.

I'm not sure why you have an aversion to using Babel, but you can pick the transformations that are applied, you can use it [programmatically](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/#usage-via-node-api), and you can even use a [standalone version](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone#usage) that works in the browser, so I think it should suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, that's the conclusion I've arrived at as well: My understanding now is that the Facebook team deliberately migrated to a Babel-based approach (whereas the initial JSTransform implementation merely relied on Esprima) - so in the absence of well-established alternative implementations, it's probably best to stick with that official one.

Answer (score 2):

This may be interested: https://github.com/RReverser/acorn-jsx

Finally two older projects that could still be useful for you:
https://github.com/facebookarchive/jstransform

https://github.com/alexmingoia/jsx-transform

Comment: "Maybe use the JSX compiler that the project provides: https://github.com/jsx/JSX"

That's a different JSX

Comment: Thank you - please see my comment to irrelephant's answer.